# Process data with one controller with no model and no database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a little test and want to see if my thinking is correct.

I have a form that is going to take in a string of data. When its submitted, it going to do some formatting and then display the formatted data.

I originally thought to have the form in the index action, post the data to create then redirect back to index with the formatted data. I don't like this because the formatted data is appended url with a query string (too ugly)

Is it reasonable have the form post to the index action and format the data in a helper method and display it. My index method would look something like this:

```
def index
  if params
    # Do Stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just render from the `create` action?

Comment: If you are not going to perform CRUD operations on form submission, you could just write formatting logic in CoffeeScript, so you could format the value in your input field on either a button click or after every keypress without submitting the form.

Comment: What jvillian suggests is probably the easiest/cleanest. Otherwise, I see no problems with posting to index. You don't have a resource here anyway, looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might achieve what you're looking for by using a table-less model (no DB connection required) and the built in `ActiveRecord` niceties to display this for you.

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email
  ...
end
```

Then display in your index action, and use the form to send a `POST` to create, and then simply display a template which shows the formatted data.

```
# controller
def index
  @person = Person.new
end

def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)
  render :formatted # formatted.html.erb
end

# index.html.erb
<%= form_for @person %>
  ...
<% end %>
```